# Bash Script with Multiple if statments

Tags: bash, if-statement

So I am trying to get email notifications setup on about 100 servers and I am using an if script that works perfectly, however I have a tool that ssh's into each machine ever 5 min to gather statistics. I am trying to adapt the script to ignore any ssh attempts from 1 IP. I have racked my brain and I think I have looked through every possible question on the subject. Any help would be amazing thank guys!!!

Currently the script sends an email no matter who ssh's in.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Change these two lines:
sender="fromtest@test.com"
recepient="test@test.com"

if [ "$PAM_RUSER" != "192.168.1.10" ]; then
goto done
next
 if [ "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
  host="`hostname`"
  subject="SSH Login: $PAM_USER from $PAM_RHOST on $host"
  # Message to send, e.g. the current environment variables.
  message="`env`"
  echo "$message" | mail "$sender" -s "$subject" "$recepient"
 fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Change these two lines:
sender="fromtest@test.com"
recepient="test@test.com"

if [ "$PAM_RHOST" != "192.168.1.10" -a "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
    host="`hostname`"
    subject="SSH Login: $PAM_USER from $PAM_RHOST on $host"
    # Message to send, e.g. the current environment variables.
    message="`env`"
    echo "$message" | mail "$sender" -s "$subject" "$recepient"
fi
```

This solution uses a different conditional to skip the body of the `if` if the `PAM_RHOST` variable is equal to `192.168.1.10`.  We use `-a` (and) to specify that both conditions must be met.

Comment: Sorry I will edit that, yes I have the # in front of the shebang. I changed my script but I still get an email whenever the IP 192.168.1.10 logs in. Any Ideas, and thank you so much for the quick response!!!

Comment: @Dale You're comparing `$PAM_RUSER` with 192.168.1.10, instead of `$PAM_RHOST`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thank you!!! that was an oversight now it works 100%. Thank you everyone!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `-a` is all but deprecated. Use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead (a separate `test` command for each condition).